# how splitt a multipage bmp file

Tags: tiff, bmp

I have scanned multi-pages into one bmp file. I can see the pages inside the bmp file only using the windows photo viewer.
 When I try to print each picture which is inside the bmp file, it only prints the first page. I have tried to save it as pdf but it does not show any save as option by right-clicking. 
I only could rename the bmp to Tiff which can be opened by the windows photo viewer.
 How can I split that one bmp file into different files so I can edit them? or save it as a pdf file that shows inside pictures?

Thanks,

Comment: Copy each page and save separately. If MS tools don't work, try IrfanView, https://www.irfanview.com/

Comment: Hello DrMoishe Pippik, Thank for replying. It is a BMP file. I only can open it with Microsoft photo viewer to see the inside pages. There are "Copy" and "make a copy" options in the Microsoft photo viewer. I tried both but it copies the file not the page inside the file. :(

Comment: IrfanView doesn't open it? Then it's not a BMP.